# Docker Compose up - Not all services are starting up

Tags: spring, docker, gradle, docker-compose, dockerfile

Need to boot up all declared service in docker-compose.yml

All except service is booted up

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'
services:
  service:
    image: ${BUILD_IMAGE_TAG}
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL= jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/CricketScore
  db:
    image: postgres
  xray:
    image:
```

MakeFile:

```
PROJECT     ?= **ProjectName**
BUILD_TAG   ?= build-local

BUILD_IMAGE_TAG = $(PROJECT):$(BUILD_TAG)

export BUILD_IMAGE_TAG
```

While running :  `docker-compose up`

Error :

```
WARN[0000] The "BUILD_IMAGE_TAG" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
service "service" has neither an image nor a build context specified: invalid compose project
```

Comment: how do you run compose up? The info you provide is not enough, imo.

Comment: I use above mentioned command only : docker-compose up

Comment: your variable will only be exported to subprocess of make when using that makefile. So if you dont run compose from your makefile, it is epxted that it doesnt "see" the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Put your variables in a .env file like so

```
BUILD_IMAGE_TAG=mytag
```

then run docker compose up --env-file=.env

Take a look [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)